# DAX: Nested sums over the same table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to write a DAX measure in PowerBI that essentially is trying to do the following in sudocode:

Where A is the data table and a is a row element of A.

```
SUMX(A,
   SUMX(A,
      a_outer - a_inner
    )
)
```

My best attempts have been to use the EARLIER function though I understand this is mostly meant for calculated columns and have been unable to get this to work.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

---

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate on what it is you're trying to do? Ideally a sample example of expected results.

Comment: Hi Rory I've added a pic that hopefully shows what the measure should be doing, so for each entry it takes the difference between it and all the other entries, sums them and then repeats for the other entries. The result will always be zero as it'll cancel out but when i split it out by the outer loop and expect to see that -6, -2, 2 6 pattern. Hope this helps, Cheers

Comment: ok, i can't really do the formal math jargon.  But if we take the Cartesian product of a table and itself (A and A', where x is and element from A and y is and element from A'), every pair (x,y) will be partnered with a pair (y,x).  So  every two values in your table will follow the form (x-y)+(y-x) => x-x+y-y => 0.    Is this really what you're trying to do?  It's always zero.

Comment: Right, its not quite what I want to do but gives the difficult part of the problem the function i'm doing is mroe complicated than just a difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This measure:

```
Test =
SUMX (
    MyTable,
    VAR Outer_A = MyTable[A] 
    RETURN 
    SUMX ( ALL ( MyTable[A] ), Outer_A - MyTable[A] )
)
```

gives this result:

[image]

MyTable[A] here refers to the column in your table that contains "a". The way it works:
in the first loop, we store a in a variable. In the second loop, we need to iterate over all "a"s, so we use ALL function. During each iteration, we subtract current "a" from the "a" saved in the variable.

Comment: My precise reaction to this was:  Wait, there's... why.. how... you...    hmmm.   I did not know you could declare variables and make return statements inside a function.

Comment: Hi Rado, thanks for that this does work. I did see something like this while trying to get this to work and it also does confuse me a bit. Do you know what you could do if you wanted to say add a third loop in were you would need to declare two variables and how this could work with only a single return statement. As you would need to declare each varable within their respective sumx?

Comment: @James - you can add as many nested loops as you need. Each loop can have its own set of variables, and its own return (that is, if you have 3 loops, you might have 2 Returns. Just make sure VAR and RETURN are matching withing each loop.